# How to calculate a vector from an angle with another vector in 2D?

Tags: math, trigonometry

I know I should know this, but I just can't figure it out/find the solution. I can do it by hand, but I can't put it in an algorithm... (working in c++, but pseudocode should be fine).

I have a vector, and I want to find another vector based on the angle with it.

[image: Angle with two vectors]

v is known, angle alpha is known and the magnitude of w is known. How can I find w?

Thanks!

Comment: Try posting on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To rotate a vector v = `(x, y)` by an angle `alpha` clockwise about the origin, you can multiply by the matrix:

```
[  cos alpha    sin alpha ]
[ -sin alpha    cos alpha ]
```

Thus the rotated vector with the same magnitude will be

```
(x cos alpha + y sin alpha, -x sin alpha + y cos alpha).
```

To change the magnitude from |v| to |w|, multiply both co-ordinates by |w|/|v|.

Comment: Thanks! This shows exactly the expected behavior :) (Now that I see this, I even remember the slide that taught me this 6 years ago >.<).

Comment: This solution only applies if rotation is about the origin. Nowhere in the question does it state that the vectors are about the origin.

Comment: I think it should be:

(x cos alpha - y sin alpha, x sin alpha + y cos alpha)

Answer (score -2):

vector(w) = vector(v) / cos (alpha) to find the direction of w.
You must multiply by magnitude(w)/magnitude(v) to set the magnitude

Comment: Hmm, this didn't seem to work for me. Could be that I'm doing something wrong though...